# Qbittorrent plugins are gone and will not reinstall

Tags: windows, plugins, qbittorrent, jackett

Asking for a friend. Friend is not very computer literate and I don't torrent.

Friend uses a program called Qbittorrent, and - with the usual claims of "I didn't change anything" - the plugins have vanished. I was skeptical, but cannot get them to reinstall and search shows that others have had this problem, but I can't find a solution that works.

Fiend says that the Jackett plugin is the most important, but would like to get all recovered/reinstalled.

[Update] Windows 10.

Also, "update all" (search plugins) doesn't work, but it does say that all of them are not supported - so, it knows which I had installed. How? If I can find that & delete it, maybe I have a chance?)

---

[Ipdate++} And, suddenly, after removing Jackett and rebooting, this morning I find that Update All works - including for Jackett !!  I have a happy friend - and I am glad to see the back of that favo(u)r

Comment: Is your friend on Windows?

Comment: please accept my apologies. Upvote, and question edited + tag added

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall qBittorrent, clean out its folders and reinstall?

Comment: I guess that I will tray that. I see no other way forward :-(

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `%LOCALAPPDATA%` folder (press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>  and type `%LOCALAPPDATA%` in the box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Delete these two directories:

`qBittorrent/nova3/__pycache__/`

`qBittorrent/nova3/engines/`

And this file:

`qBittorrent/nova3/__init__.py`

Then you can install the plugins as normal.

https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/issues/11149#issuecomment-531564986

If that doesn't work, look at https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/issues/13122

Comment: I am sorry, but I am still getting "plugin is not supported" for all that I try :-( Also, 1) running Python from the command line shows v3,10 and 2) the suggestion from your second link to "update all" (search plugin" doesn't work, but it does say that all of them are not supported - so, it knows which I had installed. How? If I can find that & delete it, maybe I have a chance?)

Comment: And, suddenly, after removing Jackett and rebooting, this morning I find that Update All works - including for Jackett !!

Answer (score 1):

Not trying to answer, but I cannot make a comment. Unlike all of the other plugins, Jackett requires an API Key, I always disable it. That search feature inside QBittorrent is awesome, but there are other, safe, ways to find torrent links which you can then add to QB with 'Open Link' button. I suggest searching for torrents by [**YTS**](https://yts.mx/) or **YiFi**. You want to copy the **Magnet Link** for the torrent and paste that into QB.
I know this comment is *late* but if your friend is still using Windows, this maybe the easiest/simplest way for future (re)installs.

Answer (score 1):

For me the trickiest thing was to find out my qbit installation didn't come installed with `jackett.py` python script supposed to be located at

> username/AppData/Local/qBittorent/nova3/engines/

on windows. You can find the script [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qbittorrent/search-plugins/master/nova3/engines/jackett.py).

I found [SkinParticular9270](https://www.reddit.com/user/SkinParticular9270/)'s description on reddit very helpful so here goes it:

Using the windows version.

Hopefully this will help some people because I had a huge problem finding the solution anywhere. If you have never used the search engine function of qbittorrent once you download jackett you still need the plugin. The git hub page tell you where to download said plugin but instead just leads you to the script. So if you can't find the Nova 3 folder and don't have the .py here is what you do.

In Qbittorrent go to view Search engine

Search plugins option in the right.

Click close. (If you want to add specific plugins you can get them here but you will see the same problem as the jackett.py link.)

This will create the Nova folder when you close QBittorrent

Next go back to the https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qbittorrent/search-plugins/master/nova3/engines/jackett.py

Right click the page and save as.

Locate your now Nova 3 User/YourUserName/AppData/Local/qbittorrent/nova3/engines/ and save file there. Should already be saved as Jackett.py

Now create the config file cause it won't exist use https://github.com/qbittorrent/search-plugins/wiki/How-to-configure-Jackett-plugin the if config file doesn't exist section of the page.

Once you create config file open it up with notepad or what ever text editor you use. Paste your api key where it says and click save.

Open qbittorrent and go to the search tab again.

Open Search plugins in the bottom right.

Click update.

It should work now. Anything you added to Jackett should now be searchable. Anytime you update jacket be sure to update search engine as well. You can also now add the search engines on the https://github.com/qbittorrent/search-plugins/wiki/Unofficial-search-plugins but Jackett already has like 90 and it can test before adding. So I would suggest using Jackett. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! Normally we do not ost "tahnk you" comments, as an upvote is enough, but I wanted to say that this an excellent, helpful, and detailed, answer froma  new contrribtor. Welcoem on board! I am sure that you will bring great value to the site